# a simple SQL join in LINQ not working

Tags: c#, linq

Consider these 2 classes.

```
class OrderDetail {int Specifier;}

class Order
{
  OrderDetail[] Details;
}
```

Now I have a List I want to enumerate over, selecting only the objects with a Specifier  of 1. As this is easy in SQL I thought LINQ with a join would be good for this but I dont know how to build the query.

```
from o in orders join o in o.Details on o.Id equals od.Id where od.Specifier = 1 select od
```

This gives an error that 'o' does not exist in the current context after join. 
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
orders.SelectMany(o => o.Details.Where(od => od.Specifier == 1))
```

In your query you are using same sequence variable name `o` for details, you should use `join od in o.Details`. But join is not needed here, because order already contains details:

```
from o in orderes
from od in o.Details
where od.Specifier == 1
select od
```